# kdb uses the symbol ' to compare strings one by one

Tags: string, list, each, kdb

I want to use ' to compare strings in a list, the code is as follows:
"tbl" ~'("customer";"tbl")
but reported an error：“length: Incompatible list lengths”。

The result I want to get is 01b
This can be done with each：
{"tbl"~ x} each ("customer";"tbl")
Please tell me how to accomplish this task with '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of each-both `'` you want to use each-right `/:`

```
"tbl"~/:("customer";"tbl")
01b
```

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right